# Meaning of $T_{\alpha(t)} M$ of curve $\alpha(t)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $M$ be a maniofld and $\alpha : [0,1] \rightarrow M$ be a curve. Then what is the meaning of $ \beta(t) \in T_{\alpha(t)} M$?

Is $\beta$ is parallel to $\alpha(t)$? or  parallel to $\alpha'(t)$?

First I know meaning of $T_p M$ for $p \in M$. i.e., tangent plane at $p$ on $M$ but what if the subscript becomes curve? I know for the differentiable map $\varphi, \Phi$, $T_{\varphi(p)}M, T_{\Phi(p)}M$ are well-defined and saw them a lots but wondering about the curve $\alpha(t)$.

Comment: I'd read $\alpha(t)$ as a point of $M$, and $\beta(t)$ as an arbitrary tangent vector to $M$ at $\alpha(t)$, so generally not parallel to either $\alpha(t)$ or $\alpha'(t)$.

Comment: For a general manifold, asking 'is the point $\alpha(t)$ parallel to the vector $\beta(t)$' is meaningless.

Comment: $T_pM$ is the tangent space of $M$ in $p$. You are looking at the case where $p=\alpha(t)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From do Carmo, Differential geometry textbook, I realized $w(t) \in T_{\alpha(t)} M$, if $x(u,v) = \alpha(t_0)$, then $w(t) = a x_u + b x_v$, where $x_u,x_v$ denote the $u$,$v$ derivatives of $x(u,v)$.